# numpy get mask from the array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array

```
a = np.array([0, 8, 25, 78, 68, 98, 1])
```

and a mask array `b = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`

Is there an easy way to get the following array:

`[8, 25, 68]` - which is first, second and forth element from the original array. Which sounds like a mask for me.

The most obvious way I have tried is a[b], but this does not yield a desirable result.
After this I tried to look into [masked operations in numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html) but it looks like it guides me in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are both numpy arrays and `b` is strictly 1's and 0's:

```
>>> a[b.astype(np.bool)]
array([ 8, 25, 68])
```

It should be noted that this is only noticeably faster for extremely small cases, and is much more limited in scope then @falsetru's answer:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,2,5)

%timeit a[a==1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.39 µs per loop

%timeit a[a.astype(np.bool)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.44 µs per loop
```

For the larger case:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,2,5E6)

%timeit a[a==1]
10 loops, best of 3: 59.6 ms per loop

%timeit a[a.astype(np.bool)]
10 loops, best of 3: 56 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 8, 25, 78, 68, 98, 1])
>>> b = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
>>> a[b == 1]
array([ 8, 25, 68])
```

Alternative using [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.compress(a, b))
[8, 25, 68]
```